# Paypal payment integration available in India

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, braintree

I am integrating Payment gateway to my Php based website

As I am from **India****(non U.S.)** so, for that I am trying to integrate payment from  **Paypal** ,but do I need to integrate with  **brainTree payments** ,

> Is Paypal payment integration there for **Indian product accepting
>   foreign clients payments**

Answer (score 0):

PayPal and braintree available in india, you can implement in your app or website, 
difference is PayPal will redirect to PayPal page during payment and braintree not

Answer (score 0):

If you have Indian PayPal business account and want to receive from cross border customer and site is PHP based which i assume is a custom website. Integrate PayPal Express Checkout server side / API method of Integration. Make sure that you pass respective currency codes for eg: Pass INR for your Indian Customers and crossborder currency like USD and equivlent amount to PayPal from your checkout page.